# RabbitMQ installing multiple services on windows machine

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I know there are many resources regarding my question but still i am not able to figure out exact way to install 2 services of RabbitMQ on single windows machine.

I know there are two way to run rabbitmq. Either as service or application. When we install RMQ it will by default install one sevice under name "RabbitMQ" which we can always run. And other way you can use below commands and run another instance of RMQ.

```
set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673
set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=test1
set RABBITMQ_SERVICE_NAME=test1
set RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS=-rabbitmq_management listener [{port,15673}]
call rabbitmq-server -detached
```

Using above commands, i am able to run second instance but as soon as user log out, the RMQ will stop. So i tried creating bat file and register it as service and start it. But even after this, the RMQ is stopping as user is Logged out.

Can some one help me with exact steps to replicate on windows machine to run long lasting second instance of RMQ (may be bat file or any other guide)??

Is there any way to modify rabbitmq-service.bat to accomodate above variable changes?

I have visited almost every website regarding installing multiple instances of RMQ but no one clearly define fine grained steps to do so.

Comment: Rabbitmq has good isolation with separate vhosts - i.e. why not run a single server with multiple vhosts if the server has  additional capacity?

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i want to use HA feature. If the rmq node goes down, both vhost are down. Hope it clears my concern. Is there any way i can register two services which i can just start and stop from windows service manager?

Comment: Running 2 instances on the same machine is still just single point of failure, if you ask me. HA is really supposed to spread out to multiple machines.

Answer (score 2):

You should carefully read this documentation: [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html#running-windows-service)

First, install RMQ as a Windows Service "normally", without any customization or environment configuration, using one administrative user on your server.

Then, create a **second administrative account**, and do the following:

Create the file `%AppData%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq-env-conf.bat` file with these contents (be sure to replace `HOSTNAME` with your actual host name!):

```
set SERVICENAME=RabbitMQ Server (2)
set NODENAME=rabbit2@HOSTNAME
set NODE_PORT=5673
```

Create the file `%AppData%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.conf` with these contents:

```
management.listener.port = 15673
```

Open a "RabbitMQ command prompt (sbin)" command prompt, and run this command:

```
rabbitmq-service.bat install
rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

You should see a second service running in the service manager.

Note that I have not tested these steps at all.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the ports and the node name in `rabbitmq-defaults`, `rabbitmq-env` and config files. One can run as a service by default and the you can just download it and create the service after you have changed the ports and node name.

[Here](https://lazareski.com/multiple-rabbitmq-instances-on-1-machine/) is a detailed guide on how to do that. It's pretty easy and straightforward.