# Rabbitmq suggestion for implementing call back queue feature

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, high-availability, spring-rabbit

I came across call back queue feature in RMQ. And its pretty fancy too. The whole idea is I have created One Message queue (queue1), its callback queue(queue1_cb) and its dlq(queue1_dlq). I am implementing HA feature with 2 nodes.

The problem comes when I am deploying 2 instances of my application(I have one sender and one receiver app in **Spring boot**). Both are listening to same HA cluster. The scenario is as below.

1. Sender publishes a message to RMQ.
2. Receiver app consumes message. Receiver app has to call third party API which is socket based API and its asynchronous so i do not get response in same connection. SO i store object of **Channel** & **Message** which i need to ack the message. (Please note i am delaying the ack till i receive response from third party API.
3. When i deploy 2 instances of receiver app, any instance will get response from third party API. And both will not have object of **Channel** and **Message** to ack message and send message to callback queue.

Can any one suggest me a solution on proiority?
Below is my code.

At Receiver side :

```
    @Override
public void onMessage(Message arg0, Channel arg1) throws Exception {

    String msg = new String (arg0.getBody());
    AppObject obj = mapper.readValue(msg, AppObject.class);

    Packet packet = new Packet();
    packet.setChannel(arg1);
    packet.setMessage(arg0);
    packet.setAppObject(obj);

    AppParam.objects.put(
    String.valueOf(key , packet);

    //Call third party API

}
```

At the time of acking and sending callback message:

```
public boolean pushMessageToCallBack(String key , AppObject packet, Channel channel, Message message){
    RabbitTemplate replyRabbitTemplate =  //Get the RabbitTemplate object. It is handled properly.
    replyRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(packet);
    channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different callback queue for each instance or, more simply, just use [Direct Reply-to](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#direct-reply-to) where you don't need a queue at all.

Comment: Hi Gary, i can not use direct reply to as i have implemented Callback queue feature. The architecture has been designed so that i have to use use this feature. Because my all processes are asynchronous. Please let me know how to implement different callback queue for each instance. Also i am storing channel object to ack later. I am not able to use cache or any other java synchronisation as channel class is not implementing Serializable interface. Is there any other way i can ack to original msg without using channel object?

Comment: Also is it possible for you to reply on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51986234/3349753

Comment: One more imp reason is if you notice i am sending message in callback queue and then acking original msg to ensure i do not end up with inconsistent state of particular transaction. In case i want to scale down callback queue consumer instance i check if there are any anacked msg or not?

Comment: The proper solution is to have the originator add his callback queue name to the `replyTo` header and reply to that. Each instance using a separate callback queue. No; you can't ack without the original channel. You can use an `AsyncRabbitTemplate` on the originator side and all of this will be taken care of for you (it can use direct reply-to, or a separate reply queue for each instance).

Comment: I can not afford creating one thread per Future task thread for AsyncRabbitTemplate. I already have enough threads created on server and i will be processing millions of requests on Prod Env. So rabbitmq will be creating thread per consumer. Anyway i changed my application logic and used Direct Reply to feature. Thanks.